# Compilation Error in simple asp.net login form (requires object reference?)

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

Help! I am making a web application that is to be hosted on a simple website. It is just a simple login application, on its own page. All it must do is login when the right credentials are given (i have a premade database with usernames and passwords). I am doing this in a vb .aspx file and cannot figure this out (i am no vb expert).

The error i am getting when running the page is this compilation error:

*Compiler Error Message: BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.*
The error occurs on line 19: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)`

Here is my code from the  default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Configuration"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">


    Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        End Sub
        Public Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from users where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Response.Redirect("welcome.html")
            Else
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
</script>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtUserName_TextChanged" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUser" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPWD" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPWD" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPWD" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It happends when you press then button or when you try to open the page? Seems to me that txtUserName is unkown to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the Lines:

```
Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

and

```
End Class
```

when writing inline code , this shouldn't be present.

Also, You may need to correct the `Else` statement.

```
Dim cstext1 As String = "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</"+"script>"
```

Now put this variable: cstext1 inside `RegisterStartupScript`

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "validation", cstext1)
```